# Gmail api get labels avoid capital letters

Tags: ios, gmail, gmail-api

I'm currently using Gmail api and getting gmail api labels return capitalized letters.

Like `Inbox` is returned as `INBOX`

```
    id = INBOX;
    name = INBOX;
    type = system;
```

Could anyone please share what query to pass to get correct label names?

Comment: Google api stores the value id/name as returned by API and thats the correct value. Most probably how its shown on UI (camel case) is taken case by frontend codebase. To answer your question the value returned from Gmail API are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API, system labels (e.g. `INBOX`, `SPAM`, etc.) are capitalized, there's just no way to return them "correct" (as in the UI).

If you want to retrieve the label with only the first letter capitalized, you'll have to modify the label string after it is returned by the API.

#### Reference:

- [Types of labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels)